# SQL query to get process completed record

Tags: sql

I have to get record for which all process completed .

Table:

```
Id Process_ind run_id
1  Y 100
2 Y 100
3 Y 100
4 Y 200
5 Y 200
6 N 200
```

SO in this case i only want run_id as output bcz all process ind are 'Y'. Id is a primary key

Comment: If  process completed refer to process_ind then I think your query should be like this.   Select run_id from table where process_ind = 'Y'

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc...) that you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `not exists` :

```
select t.*
from table t
where not exists (select 1 from table t1 where t1.run_id = t.run_id and t1.Process_ind = 'N');
```

If you want only `run_id` then you can also go with `GROUP BY` :

```
select run_id
from table t
group by run_id
having min(Process_ind) = max(Process_ind) and min(Process_ind) = 'Y';
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is something like:

```
select distinct run_id from your_table where process_ind = 'Y'
```

Comment: This will list run_id 200 also. I do not want 200 as it has one process_ind='N'.

Answer (score 0):

A GROUP BY and a HAVING would do.
Using a CASE WHEN in a COUNT can give you a specific total.

```
SELECT run_id
FROM Table
GROUP BY run_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(CASE WHEN Process_ind = 'Y' THEN 1 END)
ORDER BY run_id
```

Comment: @DevS Nice. Then we can conclude that your database type at least supports CASE WHEN.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `not in`

```
    select distinct run_id from your_table 
where run_id not in( select run_id from your_table where process_ind = 'N' )
```